# enroll_table three field fetch to payment form to create payment field in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

[image]
(figure 1)
The above figure 1 image is the snapshot of enroll table, (it belong to the enroll model, enrolls table)

[image]
(figure 2)

Figure 2 is the page view.
My question is when I click pay button, (it belongs to the Payment model, payments table),
This Enroll student_id, course_id, course_fee should be transferred to the payment id where need to save these and

[image]
(figure 3)

figure 3 -> have additional detail padi amount and ...etc.

I Tried in Model it does not support that individually seperate

payment controller details:

```
   public function index()
{
    //
    // return view('payment.index');

    // $enroll_list = DB::table('enrolls')->groupBy('id')->get();

    $enroll_list = Enroll::all();

    return view('payment.index')->with('enroll_list', $enroll_list);


    // id   enroll_id   student_id  course_fee  paid_amount     paid_date   next_due    last_balance 
}
```

enroll index page pay button code:

```
   <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#payFee"><i class="fa fa-money"> PAY </i></a></td>
```

How can I transfer the enrol fields to student_id, and batch_id to create a page of the Payment form. Meantime, I should save the payment form in the payments table
please help me

Comment: If I have understood correctly, you want to inject your data (student_id, batch_id ...) inside your payment page ?

Comment: Yes, of course,  @ThéoChampion , I do not know how to retrieve this from Payment. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Haa I got the answer for my above posts as follows,

(Figure 2: Student Registration Overview :
When I click **pay** button it should send the *student id along with the course id*.)

Step 1:

```
<td><a href="{{ route('payment.fetch', $enroll->id )}}" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" role="button">  <i class="fa fa-money"> PAY </i></a></td>
```

Now I can retrieve the data from the **Enroll ID,**
then I should take the Data From,

Step 2:
the below form on *payment creates page*
(fetch Record)

```
<form action="{{ route('payment.store',['id'=>$enrolls->id])}}" method="post">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
```

Now I can Call all of the data from the enrol table.

step 3:
I need to set the URI/ route
**On Route:**

```
Route::get('/enroll/{id}', 'PaymentController@fetchEnroll')->name('payment.fetch');
```

step 4:
**on Controller:**

```
 public function fetchEnroll($id){

        $user = Auth::user();
        $enrolls = Enroll::findOrFail($id);

        return view('payment.enroll_fetch',compact('enrolls','user'));
    }
```

Now the view page perfectly working without issues. this answer could be helpful.

***pls, give your comments if there are any mistakes.
Thank you.***